# What is the correct way to release a GCD dispatch queue property?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, grand-central-dispatch

I'm using a dispatch_queue which is accessed through a property of its owner, like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) dispatch_queue_t queue;
```

Note the `assign` keyword. The queue is used throughout the objects life and thus owned by the object. I release the queue when the owning object is deallocated:

```
-(void)dealloc
{
    dispatch_release(self.queue);
    self.queue = nil;
}
```

How do I properly release this? Would using `retain/release` work?

What happens if there is stuff pending/running on the queue while calling release?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The following is stolen from the developer documentation:

> Dispatch queues and other dispatch
>   objects are reference-counted data
>   types. When you create a serial
>   dispatch queue, it has an initial
>   reference count of 1. You can use the
>   dispatch_retain and dispatch_release
>   functions to increment and decrement
>   that reference count as needed. When
>   the reference count of a queue reaches
>   zero, the system asynchronously
>   deallocates the queue.
>
> When your application no longer needs
>   the dispatch queue, it should release
>   it with the dispatch_release function.
>   Any pending blocks submitted to a
>   queue hold a reference to that queue,
>   so the queue is not deallocated until
>   all pending blocks have completed.
>
> Note: You do not need to retain or
>   release any of the global dispatch
>   queues, including the concurrent
>   dispatch queues or the main dispatch
>   queue. Any attempts to retain or
>   release the queues are ignored.

**So anywhere you would use -retain use dispatch_retain and anywhere you would use -release use dispatch_release.**

Dispatch queues follow the same general memory management conventions as objective-c objects. And they won't be dealloc'ed until all blocks queued are finished.

If you do want a way to shut down a dispatch queue: There's no way to cancel all enqueued blocks via any sort of API, so they always must run to completion. One way to expedite this process is to have a BOOL variable in the class managing the dispatch queue: _isValid. When you want to shut down the queue, you can set _isValid to NO. All blocks submitted to the queue should first check _isValid before doing any work.

A side comment: It may be more appropriate to use NSOperationQueue. See Chris Hanson's [blog post](http://eschatologist.net/blog/?p=232).

Comment: Surely if you had a _isValid in the class, which is set in the dealloc, the object would be destroyed meaning the _isValid could no longer be read safely - what is a way around this?

Comment: Actually it would seem calling dispatch_group_wait would avoid this issue altogether.

Comment: @CiscolPPhone "the object would be destroyed" -- actually, wouldn't accessing the property inside the block increment its retain count, so it would stay around til the completion of the block, even after dealloc? I've been bit by this so I generally only reference weak properties in the block (prior to the block I make a `__weak MyClass weakSelf = self`, then in the block just use weakSelf.property. Then if the block executes after dealloc it just hits a nil weakSelf.property & dies safely.)

Comment: As for the issue of no way to cancel enqueued blocks. This is from the man-page on OSX: "If the event handler block is changed while the source is suspended, or from a block running on a serial queue that is the source's target queue, then the next event handler invocation will use the new block." also: "To unset the event handler, call dispatch_source_set_event_handler_f() and pass NULL as function." (even to un-register a block).

Comment: @CiscoIPPhone Stephen isn't active on SO. Can you answer this: He says: 
"Any attempts to retain or release the queues are ignored." then later says "anywhere you would use -release use dispatch_release." **Why would I be using dispatch_release if it's getting ignored?!**

Answer (score 8):

One interesting thing about this is that if the blocks submitted to the queue reference the object that owns the queue (e.g. "self"), the object will not hit `dealloc` until all pending blocks in the queue are completed anyway.

Here is a project that demonstrates this:

https://github.com/joshrl/GDCQueueDeallocTest

Answer (score 2):

> What happens if there is stuff
>   pending/running on the queue while
>   calling release?

It is safe. pending/running queue is retained from system. Calling dispatch_release just affects the retain count of the queue. See man page of dispatch_async or so forth.

Answer (score 2):

setup your property like so:

```
@property (readwrite, strong, nonatomic) __attribute__((NSObject)) dispatch_queue_t queue;
```

Assign is implied and Strong will retain the queue telling ARC to treat it as an NSObject.